# What does it mean that KPropertyX interface which extends an expression like : () -> V

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, interface

I rest my question on an example i saw in Kotlin source code.
this is the declaration of **Kproperty0** interface in kotlin:

```
public actual interface KProperty0<out V> : KProperty<V>, () -> V {
```

Can someone explain me what usage can i make from

> () -> V

When we extend class or interface we actually inherit it's methods, property ,etc. I can't understand which use can i do with the

> > () -> V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making my own example here :

```
class Foo : () -> String {

        override fun invoke(): String {
        return "Bar"
        }   
    }
```

Which allows you to do:

```
 val result = Foo().invoke()
```

or, as pointed in the comments, you can *invoke* it straight by doing

```
Foo()().
```

So, after doing more research, I've found out that the `invoke` method is an operator function which, in this case, is also part of the lambda function (or any function), so to write the equivalent thing using an interface, you have to add the `operator` modifier

Something like the following :

```
   interface Bar {
    operator fun invoke(): String
}

class Foobar : Bar {

    override operator fun invoke(): String {
        return "foo"
    }
}
```

Essentially, this is just defining what happens when this method is being invoked

Comment: I understand the function type, i can't understand  how it can be used by subtype

Comment: Thanks. So if i understand you, the meaning of: "() -> V" is to "say" that the class implements a function named "invoke" (like a lambda expression) that doesn't get parameter and returns type V parameter?

Comment: I've updated my answer just now to show the alternative approach, but yes, this is just a shorthand approach for "forcing" a callback into your classes implementing this

Comment: Functions have an implicit `abstract operator fun invoke` that you can override in a subtype to provide the implementation of the function. But it's not very common that you would use a class to implement a function. You more typically use a lambda or pass a property reference.

Comment: @Tenfour04 this is honestly just my understanding of this after implementing it in an example, if there's something i'm missing you're welcome to write your own answer and i'll delete this, but from my understanding it's just a shorthand instead of having to declare the interface ?

Comment: `invoke` is an operator function. that means your first example could also be `val result = Foo()()`, which your second example cannot do because it doesn't mark `invoke` as an operator. But regardless, I have never come across a situation where it would be a good design choice to create a class that implements a function type. Like in this case it would make more sense to define `val foo: () -> String = { "Bar" }` rather than creating a class `Foo`.

Comment: ahh i see what you're saying, I've never seen `val result = Foo()()` but somehow it does make sense, and you're right, the second implementation definitely won't be able to use this notation, but the result would be the same for explicitly calling `.invoke` on both of these, thanks @Tenfour04

Comment: @a_local_nobody, Didn't you confuse in the place where you have written the *operation* keyword . Sorry if i'm wrong, but as i understand, the *operation* keyword belongs to the first example. Am i wrong?

Comment: the first example, with the lambda function, already overrides and internally makes use of the operator function, that's why it doesn't need it. the example with the interface does need it because it doesn't do the same thing by default as the lambda

Comment: But in the interface *Bar* you didn't use the *operation* keyword. So why in the subtype method you did?

Comment: well interestingly enough you don't have to define it in the interface, it works if you just add it to the override method, so if you don't want it there for all methods you don't have to use it in the interface

Comment: I can't understand, if a class declares that it extends : **() -> String**, it means he doesn't need to write the **operation** keyword when implementing the method? I can't understand if for implementing **invoke** method we need to declare something?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its feature of use of `actual` modifier and you have to specify it explicitly for `operator fun invoke()`.

```
public actual interface KProperty<out V> : KCallable<V>

public actual interface KProperty0<out V> : kotlin.reflect.KProperty<V>, () -> V {
   public actual fun get(): V

   public override abstract operator fun invoke(): V
}

public actual interface KProperty1<T, out V> : kotlin.reflect.KProperty<V>, (T) -> V {
   public actual fun get(receiver: T): V

   public override operator fun invoke(p1: T): V
}
```

Comment: does the *get* function relevant to the explanation? What do you mean when saying *actual* modifier feature?